# Repeated evaluation of pure expression in IO action

Tags: haskell, io, closures, ghc, inlining

I have a procedure that (a) does some IO, (b) constructs a lookup table, and (c) returns an IO action that uses the lookup table. But when compiled with `-O`, GHC (version 6.12.1) inlines the construction the lookup table, so that it is reevaluated for every call of the IO action.

Example:

```
module Main where
import Data.Array
import Data.IORef
import Control.Monad

makeAction getX getY sumRef = do
    x <- getX
    let a = listArray (0, 1000) [x ..]
    return $ do
        y <- getY
        modifyIORef sumRef (\sum -> sum + a ! y)

main = do
    sumRef <- newIORef 0
    action <- makeAction getX getY sumRef
    replicateM_ 100000 action
    n <- readIORef sumRef
    putStrLn (show n)
    where
    getX = return (1 :: Int)
    getY = return 0
```

Is this issue well-known enough to have a standard GHC-foolproof workaround - or how would you adjust the program so that `a` isn't repeatedly being allocated?

Comment: Did you tried the pragma `{-# NOINLINE #-}`?

Comment: @FUZxxl Yes, `{-# NOINLINE a #-}` on the local `a` doesn't do it.

Comment: If you want a lookup table and want to share it amongst the repeated actions, surely you should separate creating it from the @makeAction@ function? It looks like makeAction will be making an array each time regardless of inlining. Maybe you should be using an IOArray hoisted out of the makeAction function.

Comment: @stephen I like keeping things together, making it an implementation detail if and how a lookup table is used. The (related) solutions of @nominolo and @bdonlan both achieve the sharing of `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest workaround is to force evaluation by using strictness annotations.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
```

Then force allocation by simply making `a` strict using a `!` ("bang").

```
    let !a = listArray (0, 1000) [x ..]
```

Alternatively, if you are working in the `IO` monad, strictness annotations may not always help.  To force evaluation of an expression before some `IO` action is run, you can use [`evaluate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception-Base.html#v%3aevaluate).  For example:

```
    let a = listArray (0, 1000) [x ..]
    evaluate a
```

Answer (score 2):

Try forcing `a` when constructing the monadic value to return:

```
makeAction getX getY sumRef = do
    x <- getX
    let a = listArray (0, 1000) [x ..]
    return $ a `seq` do
        y <- getY
        modifyIORef sumRef (\sum -> sum + a ! y)
```