# How to properly force evaluation of pure value in IO monad?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I need to force evaluation of pure value in `IO` monad. I'm writing
higher-level interface to C bindings. On lower level I have, say `newFile`
function and `freeFile` function. `newFile` returns some id, opaque object
I've defined on lower level. You cannot basically do anything with that but
to use it to free the file *and* purely calculate something associated with
that file.

So, I have (simplified):

```
execGetter :: FilePath -> TagGetter a -> IO a
execGetter path g = do
  fid <- newFile path -- ‘fid’ stands for “file id”
  let x = runGetter g fid
  freeFile fid
  return x
```

This is initial version of the function. We need to calculate `x` before
`freeFile` is called. (The code works, if I remove `freeFile` it's all fine,
but I want to free the resource, you know.)

First attempt (we will use `seq` to “force” evaluation):

```
execGetter :: FilePath -> TagGetter a -> IO a
execGetter path g = do
  fid <- newFile path
  let x = runGetter g fid
  x `seq` freeFile fid
  return x
```

Segmentation fault. Go straight to documentation of
[`seq`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.11/base-4.8.1.0/Prelude.html#v:seq):

> The value of `seq a b` is bottom if `a` is bottom, and otherwise equal to
>   `b`. `seq` is usually introduced to improve performance by avoiding
>   unneeded laziness.
>
> A note on evaluation order: the expression `seq a b` does not guarantee
>   that `a` will be evaluated before `b`. The only guarantee given by `seq`
>   is that the both `a` and `b` will be evaluated before `seq` returns a
>   value. In particular, this means that `b` may be evaluated before `a`. If
>   you need to guarantee a specific order of evaluation, you must use the
>   function `pseq` from the "parallel" package.

A good note, indeed, I've seen people claiming different things about order
of evaluation in this case. What about `pseq`? Do I need to depend on
`parallel` just because of `pseq`, hmm… may be there is another way.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

execGetter :: FilePath -> TagGetter a -> IO a
execGetter path g = do
  fid <- newFile path
  let !x = runGetter g fid
  freeFile fid
  return x
```

Segmentation fault. Well,
[that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4913552/3687048) doesn't work in my
case. But it suggests `evaluate`, let's try it Too:

```
Control.Exception (evaluate)
Control.Monad (void)

execGetter :: FilePath -> TagGetter a -> IO a
execGetter path g = do
  fid <- newFile path
  let x = runGetter g fid
  void $ evaluate x
  freeFile fid
  return x
```

Segmentation fault. Maybe we should use value returned by `evaluate`?

```
Control.Exception (evaluate)
Control.Monad (void)

execGetter :: FilePath -> TagGetter a -> IO a
execGetter path g = do
  fid <- newFile path
  let x = runGetter g fid
  x' <- evaluate x
  freeFile fid
  return x'
```

No, bad idea. Maybe we could chain `seq`:

```
execGetter :: FilePath -> TagGetter a -> IO a
execGetter path g = do
  fid <- newFile path
  let x = runGetter g fid
  x `seq` freeFile fid `seq` return x
```

This works. But is this the right way to do it? Maybe it only works due to
some volatile optimization logic? I don't know. If `seq` associates to the
left in this case then according to that description both `x` and `freeFile`
are evaluated when `return x` returns its value. But again, which of them,
`x` or `freeFile` is evaluated first? Since I don't get seg fault, it must
be `x`, but is this result reliable? Do you know how to force evaluation of
`x` before `freeFile` *properly*?

Comment: `seq` will not introduce segfaults unless there were *already* segfaults there. Are you sure the problem is *actually* a segfault, or are you using that term to mean something other than the usual meaning? Is it possible that it is `freeFile` that is segfaulting? (I note that the two you claim don't segfault also don't execute `freeFile` -- despite how it may look to the untrained eye!) Also, unless you're using the badly-named lazy IO somewhere (e.g. `readFile` or `unsafeInterleaveIO`), there's no need to force `x` at all.

Comment: Also, I suspect that you may have misunderstood the note on `seq`. Do note carefully the distinction between *evaluating* an `IO` action -- that is, figuring out what IO to do, specifically -- and *executing* the action -- that is, performing the actual IO. The comment is talking about evaluation only; you may want to read it again carefully with this distinction in mind!

Comment: I believe that `x \`seq\` freeFile fid \`seq\` return x` does not free the file, `seq`ing an IO action does not run it - this expression says "evaluate `x` and `freeFile fid` to WHNF before returning `return x`" - but, evaluating an IO action does not 'execute' it.

Comment: @DanielWagner, it's segmentation fault in every case (except for the last one). If I run it in GHCi without `freeFile` in `execGetter` I can get the data in REPL, then manually call `freeFile` and everything works correctly. My idea now is that functions that `runGetter` uses internally should not be pure because they depend on existing `fid` which can in principle be the same for different objects during the same program run (it's kinda void pointer internally).

Comment: @DanielWagner, user2407038, good point.

Comment: What is the code for `newFile` and `freeFile` / where does it come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible problem is that `newFile` is doing some lazy IO, and that `runGetter` is a sufficiently lazy consumer that running `seq` on its output does not force all of `newFile`'s IO to actually happen. This can be fixed by using `deepseq` instead of `seq`:

```
execGetter :: NFData a => FilePath -> TagGetter a -> IO a
execGetter path g = do
  fid <- newFile path
  let x = runGetter g fid
  x `deepseq` freeFile fid
  return x
```

Another possibility that this will address is that `runGetter` is claiming to be pure, but actually isn't (and is a lazy producer). However, if that's the case, the correct fix is not to use `deepseq` here, but to eliminate the uses of `unsafePerformIO` from `runGetter`, then use:

```
execGetter :: FilePath -> TagGetter a -> IO a
execGetter path g = do
  fid <- newFile path
  x <- runGetter g fid
  freeFile fid
  return x
```

which should then work without further fiddling with forcing.

Comment: Thinking about it I come to conclusion that everything that can be broken by order of *execution* should never leave `IO`, so my approach to lower level functions was wrong (that's my first bindings project). I'll try to correct my mistakes and then report here and probably accept your answer (I'm sure the second case you're describing is what actually happening.)

Comment: Yeah, elimination of `unsafePerformIO` solves it. I have to say that this doesn't affect high-level API at all.

Comment: @Mark Such is the way of haskell. The correct answer is often natural.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Wagner's answer is fine for this use-case, but sometimes it's also beneficial to just evaluate the spine of a list and leave the list elements unevaluated (and sometimes the list items have no sensible `NFData` instance). You can't use `deepseq` for this because it evaluates everything. However, you can combine `seq` with this function:

```
evalList :: [a] -> ()
evalList [] = ()
evalList (_:r) = evalList r
```

Comment: Or shortly `evalList = foldl const ()`.